# Laravel 5.6 auto login after registration

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to login the user automatically after registration. From what I found from other answers, something like this should work, but it's not.

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]); 

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

It's adding the new user, but not logging in. It is also redirecting to the proper page. Its also using ajax to register the user

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "userregister",
    data: {_token:_token,useremail:useremail,userpassword:userpassword},
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#showloadinsignup").html('<img src="'+site_url+'/public/images/loading.gif">');
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if(result == "useraddsucess"){
            $("#showloadinsignup").html('');
            $("#emailerror").html('');
            $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-success fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a><strong>Success!</strong> User Registered.</div>");
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            formid.reset();
}
```

Comment: check `return dd(\Auth::id())` just after `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);` ?

Comment: also share routes if you are using any middleware ?

Comment: Route::get('/register', ['uses' => 'Front\Register\RegisterController@index']);
Route::post('/userregister', 'Front\Register\RegisterController@create');
Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'Front\Login\LoginController@index']);
Route::post('user/login', 'Auth\UserController@login')->name('front.login.submit');

Comment: The default Laravel behaviour is to log in the user after registration. There should be no need for this code at all so I'm guessing the problem may be elsewhere

Comment: dd didn't dump anything. It continue on to redirect.

Comment: Auto Login by default, that's what I thought. But I hired someone to build this application and apparently it's disabled somehow.

Comment: try dd(auth()->user()->id).

Check if it dumps anything.

Comment: I added the ajax fuction used to register the user. Maybe this is where the problem

Comment: OMG! I found a second Register Controller in a different folder, not in the typical Auth folder. Added the login code and it worked